# Oracle XE installation aborts with no error explanation

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I have downloaded Oracle XE 18c for Windows 64 bit, and tried to install it on a Windows 10 machine.  I checked the SHA-256 checksum and it's correct.

The installation starts fine, but when it's copying new files it suddenly says "Rolling back installation", then ends and there's no error log to look at. Any ideas?

(1) "Copying files" screen

[image]

(2) "Rolling back" screen

[image]

(3) "Finished with errors" screen
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't created a log file? That would be unusual. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/installing-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-7BF9ACDC-1281-494C-AF96-77A25B1BD67D__GUID-10D7EC8F-7817-43C1-A129-3BA5A13E608C), and look under `%Program Files%\Oracle\Inventory\logs`. (This is off-topic anyway.. not sure if it is a better fit on DBA or Super User.)

Comment: there's no even `C:\Program Files\Oracle` folder, where Oracle error logs are stored

Comment: Is `%Program Files%` set to something different? Or have you installed Oracle products before and already have an inventory somewhere else?

Comment: I found the problem, minimum requirement is Windows 10 pro and I have home

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I run "setup.exe" as administrator instead of "Oracle Database 18c Express Edition.msi" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In my case, the isntallation error was "Unable to check available memory". I had to delete old oracle windows services that had not been uninstalled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Oracle_home` to `null` and reboot your system and then, try again.
I hope that works.

**Note:**
Make sure that you have all admin privileges before installing it.

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED!  Login to your system as an administrator to set up the Oracle database.  Compyuter》Manage》Users》Administrator》properties》check out from (accunt is disabled) and Apply.after set password. Then login as administrator and install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. In my case it was caused by the value of the `PATH` variable in my environment. It was pointing to some Oracle DB binaries and libraries from "Oracle Instant Client", which I set up earlier for the `node-oracledb` Javascript connector library.

In other words, make sure your `PATH` doesn't point to any directory which contains for example a `oci.dll` file.
You can execute `where.exe oci.dll` (the '.exe' part is only necessary for PowerShell) in a command prompt to easily check that. If the command outputs anything, then you'll need to remove the relevant directories from your `PATH`, at least temporarily.

Comment: node-oracledb can use the necessary Oracle client libraries from XE, so you could remove Instant Client (depending on what features you want from the Instant Client version).

Comment: @ChristopherJones Of course. I downloaded the Instant Client in the first place so I could access a remote Oracle Database. But then I also wanted to setup a local instance for testing purposes and encountered this issue with the setup. Just wanted to share the solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the zip file in another drive but the drive that contains windows usually C:.
2. Go into the extracted Oracle directory and run setup.exe as administrator. 
   Important: Do not double-click on the MSI file eg. Oracle Database 18c Express Edition.msi.
   Note: Spaces are not allowed anywhere in the Oracle home directory path. For example, you cannot install in "C:\program files\oracle\Infra" because of the space character in "program files". The installer does not check for this until several screens after you have entered the path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Oracle XE was installed on my computer before. When checking "set path" in the command prompt, it could be seen that a reference to the previous Oracle install was in the path. After removing that from the path, the Oracle install worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also have recently encountered this issue... 
I resolved this issue by changing the storage path from `...\18.0.0.0\` to `...\18c\` 
and one more if password contain characters like `@` then at the entering password in `SQL Plus` use double quotes (").

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by using non-ASCII characters in the local username. After renaming the account, the installation continued successfully. The log file in the `%temp%` folder helped me find out about this.

Answer (score 0):

well if anyone facing the same issue and none of the solution provided worked. What I did because I had a previous version installed before.
To make the installation work work I had to delete the registry of oracle.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Ora*

For 64 bit:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE

Answer (score 0):

What I did was delete the the app folder (c:\app) that the installer partially created before rolling back, deleted the logs and temp files that it created within an inventory folder in (c:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory).
Tried the re-installation again, worked out

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your computer user name doesn't include 'Ş,Ö,İ' etc. and spaces. I changed my user name and it's solved for me.

Answer (score -2):

I just fixed it.
I fiddled for a very long time, in the end the solution was...
**rename pc-name**. I'm in very serious.

Comment: Could you please add details why you got to that conclusion?  Renaming your PC seems like an abrupt measure to take to successfully install a piece of SW.